# making a boolean toggle back and forth every second in vb

Tags: vb.net, boolean, toggle

I want to make a boolean, toggle from true to false every timer tick.
so this is what it would do if you were to print it out

```
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
```

and so on until I stop the timer. I have tried the following:

```
Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim bool As Boolean

    For tog = 1 To 2

        If tog = 1 Then
            bool = True
        Else : bool = False

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable needs to be class scope so the value is retained between ticks of the timer.

```
Public Class form1
 Private bool As Boolean

 Private Sub Timer1_tick() Handles Timer1.Tick
  bool = Not bool
  'example
  'true = not true or (false)
  'or
  'false = not false or (true)
  Debug.Writeline(bool.ToString)
 End Sub
```

If the boolean is True then the expression is `True = Not True` so it now has the False value.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand bool = not bool

Comment: im new to vb bool = not bool i dont know what to do with it

Comment: That is how you toggle a boolean, I updated the answer to help explain it.

Comment: Just run the example and check the output.

Comment: oh i am so sorry i did not add at the question part that i want it to toggle back and forth true false true false true false